# Is there any way to get the list of connected scanners from a client side LAN (Using Javascript) in an MVC application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bonjour, twain, dns-sd

We are working on an ***MVC application to scan the document from a twain direct based scanner*** which is installed in a LAN.

For the discovery of connected scanners, we are using Bonjour which exposes the list of scanners. The scanner (twain direct) also provides rest APIs to create session with the scanner, capturing data etc.

The limitation of this solution is that, it must be deployed on the same LAN where the scanners are connected. Then only, we are able to get the list of scanners using Bonjour (Dnssd).

Now, we want to modify the solution in a way, so that the application should be deployed out side the LAN and be able to get the list of available scanners of the LAN where the application is being accessed (In Browser).

We tried a package "https://www.npmjs.com/package/bonjour" but it seems to be a server side library. We also used browserfy to make a bundle.js for javascript but it did not worked.

If we can get the list of scanners in client LAN then, we will be able to use rest api with selected scanner to perform rest of the scanning tasks.

*NOTE: On the expected LAN there may not be any PC (it may be only an ipad/android/iphone and scanner) to install any other supporting software for exposing list of scanners.*

Thanks

Comment: In the end you are always going to end up needing a tunnel into the LAN the scanners are on. And for that, you'll need either a fancy router, or a PC with dual network capabilities. Speak to an IT Ops guy. Maybe he has a great idea.

Comment: I think you are not getting the problem. I want to get a list of connected scanners from an external website which will contain some JavaScript code.

Please note, the user who access the website from their machine is not going to do anything. He just access the website and get the list of scanners.

Comment: Okay. In that case, the problem is that your browser won't allow you to write Javascript that accesses the local network. You will either need to find a browser plugin that does it, or write your own.

Comment: We did something similar with Garmin GPS devices. But again, we had to use a plugin to be able to do it.